# RedHat 8.4 Kickstart Error - iscsid: Warning: Initiatorname file

Tags: redhat

I am testing a known working Redhat Kickstart procedure on upgraded Vmware software.
Our KS process uses two CDRom's. the RH ISO is attached to CD 1 and KS ISO attached to CD 2.
the KS process fails with many messages such as
localhost dracut-initqueue[1118]: Warning: dracut-initqueue timeout - starting timeout scripts

In addition the following message appears in the rdsosreport file:

Comment: Attached is the message -> iscsiid:  Warning: InitiatorName file /etc/iscsi/initiatorname.iscsi does not exist or does not contain a properly formatted InitiatorName. If using software iscsi (iscsi_tcp or ib_iser) or partial offload (bnx2i or cxgbi iscsi), you may not be able to log into or discover targets. Please create a file /etc/iscsi/initiatorname.iscsi that contains a sting with the format: InitiatorName=iqn.yyyy-mm.<reversed domain name>[:identifier].

Comment: Your question is [off-topic in StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). You have a better chance to get it answered if you move it to [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) or to [Superuser](https://superuser.com).